# What if Error is thrown from an executor's thread?

Tags: java, exception

I have a single thread pool for task execution. As far as I know, continue working after `OutOfMemoryError` is occured is very dangerous. We should terminate our application if this happens. So, consider the following:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
es.submit(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        throw new OutOfMemoryError();
    }
});
es.shutdown();
es.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println("After throwing OutOfMemoryError");
```

In this code, we have the task throws `OutOfMemoryError`. But even after throwing it continues working and prints `After throwing OutOfMemoryError`.

Is it safe? I mean, we may end up with data corruption... Should we be prepared to this sort of scenarios and design tasks to terminate the application if `Error` is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest you do

- retain and check the `Future` returned by `es.submit` this is where the Error is held.
- always run a task with a `try { doSomething(); } catch(Throwable t) { }` so you can action any Error without having to check the `Future` object which you might have discarded.

Answer (score 1):

There are two threads in the given example -- the main thread that starts the program and a thread for executing the specified tasks. All threads are allocated their own, independent from each other, stacks. However, all threads use the same memory heap. This is why the `OutOfMemoryError` effects the whole program, not just a single thread.

Generally speaking, upon termination (successfully or otherwise), the task executing thread does not effect execution flow of any other thread (unless this is what it was designed for doing). That is why, the main thread in the provided example, keeps running even though the task thread got terminated.

I would highly recommend studying the [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) book to get better overall undestanding of the Java concurrency and parallelism.

Comment: In JCIP said that we could use  `uncaughtExceptionHandler`. But it's about all exceptions, not just errors. So, I think that @PeterLawrey's suggest would be the best choice...